# There is something wrong with My Android Studio when creating a new default application.I'm new to use it

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

When using Android Studio(1.4.1) to create a new  application,the activity is the default Blank Activity,also the activtiy_main.xml is default,it contains android.support.design.widget.xxx,but the preview show nothing,what can I do to solve this.

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.buaa.arvin.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From **Android Studio 1.4+**

> **Blank Activity** is **Empty Activity**
>
> If you really intent to use blank activity go for empty activity, It'll works just fine.
>
> If you want more customization to handle by default you go for blank activity and other activity types from the gallery

**And to resolve your issue**

post your gradle code

Comment: buildToolsVersion is "22.0.1",the activity_main.xml contains the <include layout="@layout/content_main" />,and it includes a Text,it can't be shown in the preview.

Comment: xml preview or while running the app?

Comment: When running the app ,it will show all the activity